# Rails: download file with "Open With" option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running Rails 2.2.3. I have a controller that I am using to manage uploading and downloading files. I have successfully linked to files on the view to allow a user to download, but when the download dialog box opens, it only shows a Save File option. I'd like to have the "Open With" option available as well. I'm using Firefox 3.6 on Ubuntu 10.

This is the controller that is used to "send" the file to the user:

`def show`

```
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if File.exist?("#{RAILS_ROOT}/#{@document.path}")
      format.html { send_file "#{RAILS_ROOT}/#{@document.path}" }
    else
      flash[:error] = "File #{@document.path} does not exist!"
      format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
    end
  end
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the correct MIME type (and extension) to allow Firefox to recognise what kind of file is being downloaded:

```
send_file "#{RAILS_ROOT}/#{@document.path}", :type => "application/pdf",
  :filename => "document.pdf"
```

You can read and store this information when the file is being uploaded.

```
uploaded_file.content_type  # the uploaded file's MIME type
uploaded_file.original_path # name of the file
```

Even then, if the MIME type is unknown, I don't think you'll get an *Open with* prompt. So ultimately this will also depend on the particular kinds of files you are using in your application.

Comment: Isn't there a way to register Mime types? Could I then register all the different files I'm dealing with so that all files would have the open with option?

Comment: Nevermind I got the Mime type register thing to work -- now it works for all my obscure file types! :D